# cURL on Ubuntu 14: all Let's Encrypt certificates are expired (error 60)

Tags: https, ubuntu-14.04, ssl-certificate, letsencrypt

Today out of a sudden all HTTPS requests, that my Ubuntu 14 server sends to websites with SSL certificates issued by Let's Encrypt, started to fail. The error produced by cURL is:

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
```

When I inspect the website certificates with this command:

```bsh
echo -n | openssl s_client -showcerts -connect website.com:443 -servername website.com
```

I see that all the certificate chain is up to date.

So why do I get the expiration error? How to fix it?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The reason is that the "DST Root CA X3" certificate has expired yesterday.

To fix it, just disable the certificate on your server. Run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
```

On the first screen that prompts "Trust new certificates from certificate authorities?" choose "yes". On the next screen press the down arrow key on your keyboard until you find `mozilla/DST_Root_CA_X3.crt`, press the space bar to deselect it (the `[*]` should turn into `[ ]`) and press Enter.

Comment: You should add an explanation of *why* this works. It's working around a bug in old software (old OpenSSL version, maybe other TLS libraries too) on the outdated distro, whereby when it sees an expired root certificate that would prove validity of the chain, it immediately stops looking and gives an error, rather than continuing the chain to find another non-expired root that would prove validity.

Comment: I bring this up because it's important folks know the problem is **not** Let's Encrypt having a bad or unsupported certificate chain. It's broken software on the client end that's applying the rules for validating certificate chains incorrectly.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Thank you! This is what came to my mind, but I couldn't check whether it's true. When you disable the "DST Root CA X3" certificate, the ["ISRG Root X1" certificate](https://letsencrypt.org/certs/isrgrootx1.pem) (that will work until 2035) is used.

Comment: Arguably, the root of the issue is that phones/tablets require OS images built for the specific device, rather than being able to use generic installation media. That leads to a whole bunch  of phones/tablets stuck on outdated andriod which leads to "creative" certificate issuing practices in an attempt to maintain support for those clients.

Comment: Solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 31):

Edit the file /etc/ca-certificates.conf

Find and comment with `!` the line like this

`!mozilla/DST_Root_CA_X3.crt`

Save the file and update certificates with command

`sudo update-ca-certificates`

Comment: A "one-liner" to get this done is: `sudo sed -i -e 's=^mozilla/DST_Root_CA_X3.crt=!mozilla/DST_ROOT_CA_X3.crt=' /etc/ca-certificates.conf && sudo update-ca-certificates`

Comment: You upper casing it here stuffed it up for me..  Still gave the error till I went back and changed ROOT to Root.  It should be
```sudo sed -i -e 's=^mozilla/DST_Root_CA_X3.crt=!mozilla/DST_Root_CA_X3.crt=' /etc/ca-certificates.conf && sudo update-ca-certificates```

Comment: @ mikep @shanness THX!

Comment: This is only option that works for me for ubuntu 14;.04. What's happening with `DST_Root_CA_X3.crt` here?

Answer (score 7):

FYI on CentOS like (RPM Based) systems, use:

`yum reinstall ca-certificates`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1082685)

Comment: @music2myear: I guess it technically doesn't, since the OP asked specifically about Ubuntu. That said, IME answers that solve the same problem in a slightly different setting (e.g. newer OS version than the OP has, different Linux distro, etc.) are often considered helpful and welcome additions. This appears to be a problem that affects multiple Linux distros, and people who use something other than Ubuntu are likely to find this Q&A on Google too. Having an answer for CentOS and other yum-based systems is helpful for them.

Comment: I asked about Ubuntu because I use Ubuntu. If the same problem has happened on another system and has a similar solution, it's on-topic for this question.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. For some reason my machine had v2014.1.98 of ca-certificates installed. I looked through a lot of answers, and yours is the first one that I'm confident addresses the root cause of the issue.

Answer (score 4):

> So why do I get the expiration error?

Android made a design decision to ignore the expiry on root certificates (it's arguable that expiry on root certificates doesn't make much sense in the first place).

"lets encrypt" is a relatively new CA and to support existing systems their root was "cross-signed"* by DST. The DST root certificate has now expired but because of the aforementioned android behavior a cross signature is still useful for supporting clients running old versions of andriod.

When such a chain is used on a system with a modern root certificate list the cross signature should be ignored and the IRSG (lets encrypt) root should be used. Unfortunately openssl 1.0.x does not handle this scenario correctly.

This issue can be worked around by removing the old DST root certificate. When this is done the chain will correctly be built to the IRSG root.

* My understanding is that technically the "cross signature" consists of an "intermediate certificate" with the same content and key as Lets Encrypt's root certificate.

Comment: Originally LE had their _intermediates_ (first X1,X2, replaced by X3,X4) signed by DST. They now have new intermediates R3,R4,E1,E2 signed by their two roots ISRG-X1,X2, with ISRG-X1 _also_ cross-signed by DST, which has the same Subject and key and some extensions, but different issuer, serial, validity, and other extensions. Compare (as linked from https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/) https://crt.sh/?id=9314791 and https://crt.sh/?id=3958242236 . Otherwise concur.